# calling pages from database in navigateurl in materpages with pages in another folder

Tags: asp.net, vb.net-2010

First of all, I would like to apologise on the questions that I have put forth, since I didn't know how to go ahead with that

Im creating a website in asp.net using vb and i have a problem.

I have created a database to display the menu names with the location of the pages.

I have created a folder call /Pages/MasterPages in the root folder /Pages wherein the masterpage design goes in that and normal surfing pages are in the root folder

I also have a folder called /Pages/Admin wherein the CMS of the site goes into it.

Now i have the following code that calls the menu items from the database

```
<asp:Repeater ID="_menuDisplay" runat="server">
                                        <HeaderTemplate>
                                            <table id="navigation" border="0">
                                        </HeaderTemplate>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><asp:HyperLink ID="Hyperlink" runat="server" NavigateUrl=<%# Container.DataItem("pageName") %>><%# Container.DataItem("menuName")%></asp:HyperLink> </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <FooterTemplate>
                                            </table>
                                        </FooterTemplate>
                                    </asp:Repeater>
```

Container.DataItem("pageName") displays the pages/home.aspx
Container.DataItem("menuName") displays the Home (name for the home.aspx page)

The above code is in the masterpage

On execution the pagename on the internet explorer displays pages/masterpage/pages/home.aspx it should display only pages/home.aspx

Please help

Regards

Leroy M

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

1: Create a public function in your code behind page.
   i.e.

```
Public Function ResolveUrl(objValue as object) as String
     Dim sPath as String = Page.ResolveUrl(cstr(objValue))
     Return sPath  
End Function
```

2: Change code in web-page:

`NavigateUrl=<%# ResolveUrl(Container.DataItem("pageName")) %>`

3: Ensure your page name is in the format "*~/FolderPath/File.aspx*" the ~ tells the asp.net engine to map the page from the root directory of your solution.

Hope this helps.